# Why would villagers attack Orangutans?

Tags: zoology

I read today in the news that [villagers in Borneo were attacking refugee Orangutans](http://news.yahoo.com/indonesia-orangutans-attacked-villagers-fleeing-fires-102845026.html;_ylt=AwrC1zGy.EFWQAYAlhPQtDMD;_ylu=X3oDMTByOHZyb21tBGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzcg--). Why would they do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [It’s Not Just Conflict That Motivates Killing of Orangutans](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0075373) by Davis et al. (2013), the authors identify number of conflict and non-conflict reasons reported in the study why orangutans were killed in a certain part of Indonesia:

Conflict reasons:

- pest
- fear/self-defence
- paid or forced to kill
- orangutans interrupted logging or forestry operations

Non-conflict reasons:

- traditional medicine
- food
- to sell or keep young as pets
- hobby/sport hunting
- for other trade of animals or meat
- killed accidentally or opportunistically while hunting other animals

The results from this survey are depicted in this graph:

[image]

Obviously in this case they were not attacked for food. The impression I got from the article makes me think it was probably motivated by people viewing them as pests or as a threat/danger. It is almost certainly more of a social reason than a biological reason. However, in the absence of specific evidence, it is probably not helpful to speculate why this occurred.